# How to iterate through multiple-node structures in XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to iterate through multiple-node structures, but this structure is only identified by the leading node, and the nodes following that leading node can vary.

In this example, I need to iterate through each `<title>-some_nodes`, `<title>-some_other_nodes` block

XML file:

```
<books>
    <title>book_one</title>
    <price>price_for_book_one</price>
    <notes>notes_for_book_one</notes>

    <title>book_two</title>
    <price>price_for_book_two</price>
</books>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="book">
    <h1 id="title">book_one</h1>
    <h2 id="values">
        <p>price_for_book_one</p>
        <p>notes_for_book_one</p>
    </h2>
</div>

<div class="book">
    <h1 id="title">book_two</h1>
    <h2 id="values">
        <p>price_for_book_two</p>
    </h2>
</div>
```

My try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="books/title">
        <h1 id="title"><xsl:text>Title:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </h1>

        <h2 id="values">    
        <!-- have other templates for matching all possible following-sibling nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*>
        </h2>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But this only selects the title nodes without parsing any other nodes, since "books/title" only selects the title node.

Note: `<price>` and `<notes>` are two example nodes, there could be anything in between the `<title>` nodes, and I have other templates for dealing with them, but how to select them is the my problem.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to explain what "doesn't really work"... Please, edit your question and provide the exact correct result that you need and the result that you actually get. Also, describe what exactly is wrong with the actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop the context node is `title`, so it is selected with `.`.

You probably only want the first price and notes elements that follow a title. I have also used `xsl:text` to reduce the whitespace in each paragraph.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="books/title">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Title: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Price: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::price[1]"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Notes: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::notes[1]"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If the additional nodes between each `title` are not fixed, you could handle each of them with templates. The important thing here will be the XPath expression to select the non-title elements that belong to the current title.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="books/title">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Title:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[
                                       local-name() != 'title' and
                                       preceding-sibling::title[1] = current()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Price: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll edit the template for selecting the title node.
However the nodes following <title> is not determined, it could be other nodes than <price> and <notes>.

Comment: This second solution is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't seem to need grouping. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="books/*">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of
                 select="concat(translate(
                                   substring(local-name(),1,1),
                                   'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm',
                                   'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
                                ),
                               substring(local-name(),2),
                                ': ',
                                .
                         )" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<p>Title: book_one</p>
<p>Price: price_for_book_one</p>
<p>Notes: notes_for_book_one</p>
<p>Title: book_two</p>
<p>Price: price_for_book_two</p>
```

Grouping would be needed only if you are going to do something with the group, like wraping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElementByPrecedingTitle"
             match="books/*"
             use="generate-id((.|preceding-sibling::*)[self::title][last()])"/>
    <xsl:template match="books/*">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of
                 select="concat(translate(
                                   substring(local-name(),1,1),
                                   'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm',
                                   'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
                                ),
                               substring(local-name(),2),
                                ': ',
                                .
                         )" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="books">
        <xsl:for-each select="title">
            <div class="book">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="key('kElementByPrecedingTitle',generate-id())"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<div class="book">
    <p>Title: book_one</p>
    <p>Price: price_for_book_one</p>
    <p>Notes: notes_for_book_one</p>
</div>
<div class="book">
    <p>Title: book_two</p>
    <p>Price: price_for_book_two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear on the output I was looking for. I do need to tag each group, and I also need to tag the <title> nodes individually, then the rest of the group within another tag. 
Good example of using keys, definitely worth knowing. Thanks!